# Exception handling in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, exception

Which layer(Controller, Services, DAO or Utlis) is ideal to handle Exception in spring-boot? Also, should i create a new package to handle all the Exceptions globally?

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling

Comment: Ideally service layer you should handle all exceptions.Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring